# Angular- Updating the component without recreating internal components

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm building an angular8 application and one of my components has an HTML that looks like this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" style="margin: 5px">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let tile of tiles">
    <my-component [type]="tile.kind"
              [row] = "tile.row"
              [column] ="tile.column"              
              [state] = "tile.state"></my-component>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

The `my-component` component's view changes depending on inner values of `tile.state`.

I have noticed that whenever I update my `tiles` array, my view changes but it recreates all my `my-component` elements.

Is there a way to prevent the recreation of these elements and just change them according to the data in my state object?

## EDIT

I think I didn't explain myself as well as I should have...

All of the tiles in my grid should be updated, not just one of them.
My problem is that the components in the grid are being created -  I think that it really hurts the performance.
If my `<my-component>` has a `<img>` inside it, and it gets its value from the `state` object, I'd like just the `<img>` to be re-created, but the `<my-component>` should not.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[In the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#see-also) you will find `ngForTrackBy`. The syntax is

```
*ngFor="let x of y; trackBy: myFn"
```

Your function will then by

```
myFn(index: number, itemOfTheList: YourCustomType): number | string {}
```

This function will be the one tracking your elements. It should return a primitive type (boolean, number or string) to identify each object uniquely.

Once the objects have a unique ID you have made, the for loop will recreate only the ones needed.

Comment: hi, I may have not explained myself well. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look the `changeDetection` flag for your container component
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'compA',
      template: '<mat-grid-list cols="4" style="margin: 5px">
                  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let tile of tiles">
                   <my-component [type]="tile.kind"
                     [row] = "tile.row"
                     [column] ="tile.column"              
                     [state] = "tile.state"></my-component>
                  </mat-grid-tile>
                 </mat-grid-list>',
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
```

What happen now is  will only re-render when there is a new input. now if you do tiles[0].state = new State(), it will only update that one element.

Comment: hi, I may have not explained myself well. I updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should set another variable to set state, not declare it in "title" variable.

Comment: Should be a comment, and no.